# Margin shift from child element to parent element when border removed

Tags: html, css

When border of `footer` tag is removed `margin-top` of `<div id="foot">` apply on footer tag instead.

Here is the code i am using

```css
footer {
    background: #0096D6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;  
    color: #fff;
    border: #FF0004 1px solid;  
}
#foot {
    width: 1136px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 80px;   

}
```

```html
<footer>
<div id="foot">
    <div id="subscribe">
    <b>Subscribe</b><br><br>Get the latest news, events, updates and offers from the team and people working in DigitNomics.<br><br><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" />
    </div>
    <span id="development">
        <ul>
            Current Development
            <a href="#"><li>Demo</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>ALPHA Development</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>BETA Development</li></a>
        </ul>
    </span>    
</div>
</footer>
```

Here is the jsfiddle with border https://jsfiddle.net/dkp5k1yq/
In this margin-top work as expected.
And here is the seconde jsfiddle with `border:none` on `footer` https://jsfiddle.net/dkp5k1yq/1/

I don't want to use border on footer tag but when i remove border its child margin property is transferred to him.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Does the margin change from one element to another after the page has loaded and some action or event has taken place?

Comment: I don't want to use border on footer tag but when i remove border its child margin property is transferred to him.

Comment: Try to set padding-top:80px, instead of margin, it is quick fix....

Comment: Your observation is correct  I'd recommend either simply changing the border-color to match the background color or using box-sizing: border-box on the footer and converting the #foot margin to padding on the footer.  https://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/dkp5k1yq/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [MDN's Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), specifically:

> **Parent and first/last child**
> If there is no border, padding, inline
>   content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the
>   margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline
>   content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the
>   margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child,
>   then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the
>   parent.

In your first [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkp5k1yq/), the parent `footer` had a border, and therefore the margin *did not* collapse.

In your second [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkp5k1yq/1/), the parent `footer` had no border, padding, inline content, or clearance, and so the margin *did* collapse,

One solution is to change this:

```
#foot {
  margin-top: 80px;   
}
```

… to this:

```
#foot {
  padding-top: 80px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix would be to add display: inline-block to either #foot or footer tag.

Answer (score 0):

Only make in your .css the clearfix class and then apply to the footer tag

```
    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<footer class="clearfix">
```